# Batch uploading GeoTIFFS to GEE

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, satellite

I have a folder of a few thousand GeoTIFF files of several years of satellite data that I wish to upload into my assets folder on the Google Earth Engine.

The only way I know how to upload the data is to manually press 'upload' each time and add the time data to the file.

Obviously, this is not ideal for my current circumstances.

Is there any way to batch upload the files while adding the 'system: start time' data?

Answer (score 2):

You can upload through the command line.

1. [transfer images to Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) (several options)
2. bash script to loop transfer each image from GCS to EE asset using [EE command line upload](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line#upload).

Alternatively, if the images are Cloud Optimized GeoTiffs (COGS), you can import them to EE scripts directly from GCS [[reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_overview#images-from-cloud-geotiffs)]

As for adding a timestamp, set it using the EE CLI tool's `upload image` `--time_start` flag when transferring images from GCP to EE asset:

```
earthengine upload image --time_start=1593210113 --asset_id=users/username/asset_id gs://bucket/image.tif
```

Use `earthengine upload image -h` to see the other options, it's best to define as many as you can; be intentional. Work with a single image until you are satisfied with how the asset appears in Earth Engine; e.g., zoom level tiling ([pyramids](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale#image-pyramids)), band names, and image properties.

You can also use [manifest documents](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_manifest) to set other options not available through the `upload image` flags.

Comment: I've had a look at what you suggested, but I can't seem to find a way to add 'system: start time' for each image based on the satellite data? This is key for my time-series analysis.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include adding timestamp.

Comment: Great, thanks. One more question though; if I'm looping through in the command line how do I set a different 'time start' for each image? (I am not familiar with comand line interfaces).